# render inline javascript with node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have an html document with some inline javascript like this:

```
<script>
  var greeting = "hello";
</script>
```

I can access the variable and change the value of that on the server side but that will not change anything for what the client gets. Do i have to parse it as string or is there any other possibility to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a template library where you can create static HTMLs in the server and send them as-is.
[Jade.js](http://jade-lang.com/) is such library .

Comment: Unfortunately I have to take the HTML as it is.